# Visual Studio 2019 - Attach To Process hangs when listing processes in Alpine container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

I'm following the process as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Docker_Attach) to connect to a remote process from Visual Studio 2019.

If I select an [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) based container, this dialog pops up, and hangs Visual Studio.
[image]

But an [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) container works just fine. The processes on the container are listed as expected.

Is this a VS or a Alpine issue ?
Workarounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.4, with the exact same issue.

It's referenced there: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2165
and there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1102637/attach-to-process-doesnt-work-on-alpine-based-linu.html

Both references claim it is fixed...

While it was failing for me. After adding procps, it works fine:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS base
RUN apk add --no-cache curl procps
```